# Windows: Application Isolation for Testing Purposes

Tags: virtualization, isolation

I once saw an application that seperates your application in a seperate environment; has a virtual memory and registry and filesystem. It is like application isolation, but would allow any operation that I can do such as Installing applications and having administrator rights. I am not talkin about VirtualBox or other software. But I cannot find what I want. Any software offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe reminds me of [VMware ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html). It seems to be quite expensive though.

Comment: I went with free alternative, Cameyo. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about Cameyo. It can be useful for me too, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SpoonStudio ([Link](http://spoon.net/Studio/)) seems like what you're after, it was formerly called Xenocode.